# Fancybox V2 button helper conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox-2

I am trying to add button helpers on top of the gallery and it is conflicting with my 
opaque background.  Here is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
            padding: 0, // remove the white boarder around content
            openEffect  : 'fade',
            closeEffect : 'fade',

            prevEffect : 'fade',
            nextEffect : 'fade',
                    helpers: {
        overlay: {
            css: {
                'background': 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.99)' // background opaque
            }
        }
    }
  });
});
```

I am trying to add:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".fancybox-button").fancybox({
    prevEffect      : 'none',
    nextEffect      : 'none',
    closeBtn        : false,
    helpers     : {
        title   : { type : 'inside' },
        buttons : {}
    }
});
});
```

Here is a fiddle with out the button helper :  http://jsfiddle.net/h66Hp/
Help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not include the css file for the helpers found [here](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css) and to have helpers and overlay (an opaque white) and title outside this would be the code:

```
    helpers: {
        buttons: {},
        overlay: {
            css: {
                'background': 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)' // background opaque
            }
        }
    }
```

### Edit

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h66Hp/6/) showing complete with updates below

Comment: that looks like it works, do you know if there is a way to change the font color of the title without modifying the css?

Comment: you background isnt set to an set to a very opaque color i assumed you did that on purpose change the background to something like `background': 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)` and remove the `title {}` section i will update my answer now